# Need disk utility to find folders with large amount of files

Tags: disk-utility

Am having trouble with an online backup service that supposedly fails because it is finding I have some folders with an excessive number (in the millions) of small files

Need a disk utility that will help me find folder with large numbers of included files.

**Most utilities can easily find the largest folder but am looking more specifically to find the folders with the Largest Number of files.**

Any help/advice would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly a disk utility, but I found this answer after about 2 minutes of googling:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25506599/recursively-count-files-in-subfolders